# Kirby diagrams of Mazur manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 4-manifolds, kirby-calculus

In the 1980's, [Fintushel-Stern](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2006987) and [Fickle](https://www.math.uh.edu/%7Ehjm/restricted/archive/v010n4/0467FICKLE.pdf) independently proved that Brieskorn spheres $\Sigma(2,3,25)$ and $\Sigma(3,5,19)$ bound some Mazur type contractible 4-manifolds with a single $0$-, $1$, and $2$-handle.

I would like to ask that are the 4D Kirby diagrams of these $4$-manifolds known?

Comment: As remarked below, the alleged link to Fickle's paper goes to a paper of Gordon. The latter is a classic and well worth reading, but you probably mean https://www.math.uh.edu/~hjm/vol10-4.html

Comment: Sorry, I edited the link.

Answer (score 6):

The [paper](https://www.math.uh.edu/%7Ehjm/vol10-4.html) of Fickle (not the paper of Gordon to which you link) has an explicit construction for $\Sigma(3,5,19)$. It's behind a paywall but maybe you can get it from interlibrary loan or some kind soul will send you a pdf. Fickle attributes $\Sigma(2,3,25)$ to Casson-Harer, [Some homology lens spaces which bound rational homology balls](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-96/issue-1/Some-homology-lens-spaces-which-bound-rational-homology-balls/pjm/1102734944.full). Since Fickle was Stern's student, I assume he got the attribution right. I think that $\Sigma(2,3,25)$ should appear on the list at the beginning of Fickle's paper but I haven't done the arithmetic. If it's on that list, then it's not hard to write down the desired handle diagram.

The method is the same in both cases; you do surgery on a well-chosen knot in your surgery diagram of the homology sphere to get $S^1 \times S^2$, to which you attach $S^1 \times B^3$. Turning this @Upside Down gives the desired handlebody picture of the Mazur-type manifold. See also the paper of Şavk, [Classical and new plumbed homology spheres bounding contractible manifolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.12587) and his [survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.10735).

Since it's not that easy to come by, I've attached a screenshot of Stern's announcement about Brieskorn homology spheres from the Notices of the AMS (these days it would be Abstracts). I'm pretty sure it never appeared but Fickle wrote up the results in the aforementioned paper.

[image: Screen shot of Stern's announcement about Brieskorn homology spheres]

Comment: "Turning this @Upside Down" ... cute.

Comment: Thank you @Danny Ruberman. Fickle's proof is available on pg. 485. I could not turn these 4-manifolds "upside-down" and that is why I raised this question.

Comment: According to Math Genealogy, Fickle was a student of Milett https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=17168

Comment: Of course, you're right; I should have checked. I think that I heard about Fickle's work from Stern, so I had assumed he was Stern's student.